# Is QueueUserWorkItem with lock correct implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, locking, threadpool

I have implemented a logging method as follows:

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) => {
    lock (appendLock) {
       using (StreamWriter log = File.AppendText(_logFile)) {
          log.WriteLine(message);
       }
    }
 }, null);
```

1: Is the `lock` necessary? I wanted to thread the logging and found the lock already in place. So rather than alter that code, I simply wrapped into a worker delegate.

2: assuming the lock is required: is this the correct implementation to enqueue the delegate containing a lock? The potential is reasonably high that multiple threads could be requesting log-writes. By enqueueing the delegate to a worker thread, the length of a File I/O execution should not affect the application itself.

3: assume several `logWriteDelegate` workers have been enqueued: Will the delegates be invoked in the *order they were received*? i.e., ***Now serving #32 ...Now serving #33***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: yes, lock it is required. It could be accessed by multiple threads, especially since you're using the pool.

2: well, it'll work. But it will keep the file locked making it hard to read. There are pre-existing logging frameworks that have worked a lot on this problem - it may be worth using me of them.

3: no; with the lock and the pool, that's two separate reasons not to expect strict ordering in the final file. In fact, becuase of the pool, a **single thread's** messages could appear out of order. If you want ordering, you'll need to write to a (synchronized) queue, and have a dedicated worker that pulls data (synchronised) back out of the queue and writes to the log file. Again, existing logging frameworks will have solved this for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, existing logging frameworks are out of the question due to licensing, open-source, and other legal hurdles. Simply means I need to provide a thread-safe logging mechanism. Keeping the file locked is okay ...the logs are not normally read by any of the users (unless I misunderstood something).

Comment: Thanks for the info: I reworked to add a queue which enqueues a logging `Action` which is monitored by a `Task` object. Enqueueing and Dequeueing are synchronized on a `lockQueue` object as the `Queue<T>` doesn't have a synchronization object.